# Infopath / Sharepoint: auto number is listed in the worng order

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, items

I have a infopath form that saves some data to a shorepoint library. When submitting the form, the form is named after a counting Id, based on the amount of items in the list. (name = number of items in library + 1) That works fine, but after submitting some forms I discovered, that the items are ordered in an awkward way:

By filtering the ID / Name in ascending order, the items are listed this way:

1
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
2
20
21
22
..
29
3
30
31
..

Is there a proper way to order it in the correct order? The column name is created via Infopath and cannot be customized by me in Sharepoint.

Best regards,

Julian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the numbers are going into a SharePoint column whose format is text rather than number. Because of that, the numbers are getting sorted in alphabetical order rather than numeric order. The simplest solution would be to have your InfoPath form create a numeric column in SharePoint, or alternatively you could try adding leading zeros to the numbers you are sending to SharePoint from InfoPath, like this:

> concat(substring('000', 1, (3-string-length(field))), field)

This will give you 001, 002, 003, ... 010, 011, 012, ... 019, 020, 021, etc.